# Turn on or off Wifi/Bluetooth from Notification in Android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've searched a lot for this, but the searches usually give irrelevant results. Any idea how to add an Intent to a Notification, that will enable, or disable Wifi (for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no intent to change the WiFi state AFAIk, so you can't just use a pending intent. You have to combine it with a BroadcastReceiver.

The flow goes this way - your notification will wake the BroadcastReceiver (you can make a pending intent to notify the receiver), which can then change the WiFi state with the regular WiFiManager API.

Here's a working implementation of this.
https://github.com/f2prateek/shush-wifi/blob/master/shush-wifi/src/main/java/com/f2prateek/shush/wifi/TurnWifiOn.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this for bluetooth:

```
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, enableBtIntent, 0, null);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    mBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_data_bluetooth, getResources().getString(R.string.enable_bluetooth), resultPendingIntent);
```